# Is this possible to update the object received from webhook of Sitecore

Tags: xm-cloud

I tried to get the webhook JSON object on the event item:saved (like below),

```
{
  "EventName": "item:added",
  "Item": {
    "Language": "en",
    "Version": 1,
    "Id": "4c3a401e-8b78-440a-bf88-736a71ce8e5a",
    "Name": "New sample item",
    "ParentId": "8fb31904-1bbc-463c-821b-c7c1a87bf13e",
    "TemplateId": "0133f52d-271f-4217-b1cd-04342e3457eb",
    "MasterId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "SharedFields": [
      {
        "Id": "a4f985d9-98b3-4b52-aaaf-4344f6e747c6",
        "Value": "{88AD1387-D4DA-489D-BB4B-45540917E7ED}"
      }
    ],
    "UnversionedFields": [],
    "VersionedFields": [...]
  },
  "WebhookItemId": "95398c44-f232-41a8-b947-8aefec4ce6eb",
  "WebhookItemName": "Sample Webhook Event Handler"
}
```

but now I want to edit that JSON, e.g., I want to add one more property in that like ItemPath or any custom property of my own logic then how can we implement it?

Comment: Sounds like something that is described in following post will help you get on right track https://uxbee.nl/actueel/webhooked-on-a-feeling

Comment: It can be achieved by two ways. Either by creating a custom event that subscribes to sitecore system events. Or a custom event that can be triggered whenever you want with your custom json payload. See if these articles helps. https://pushpaganan.home.blog/2023/09/14/customizing-sitecore-webhooks-with-custom-event-and-custom-payload/ https://www.kjeldby.dk/2023/06/custom-webhook-events-in-sitecore-xm-and-xm-cloud/